# Is it possible to have Twitter alert me when someone tweets?

Tags: twitter, iphone

I have twitter installed on my iPhone and wanted to know if it was possible to have my phone alert me when a particular user tweets?

Answer (score 0):

> Yup, it's possible. Click on the account you want to get tweets
>   notifications from. And click on the bell Icon

Comment: NOTE: method above works ONLY on the Android and iOS apps

Answer (score 0):

One way to get it done, without being dependent on Twitter's mobile app, is by using a free action-trigger web service like [**IFTTT**](https://ifttt.com/) (If This Then That). It allows you to set new tweets from any account of your choosing as trigger and set the action to be an e-mail, SMS or even a mobile alert.

Here is a [link to a ready-made IFTTT recipe](https://ifttt.com/applets/234075p-new-tweet-by-specific-user-send-me-an-email) which will send you an e-mail each time a certain account of your choosing tweets a new tweet.

The caveat with this is that it is not really real-time but works on a 15 min. refresh cycle. That means IFTTT is checking for new tweets every 15 min. or so...